# C#/ASP.NET Nested Repeater does change list with new parent

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my C# Backend:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

            CaseEnt MyCase = McHenryLib.ICISAdapters.CaseAdapter.GetCaseRecordForCaseNumber(Globals.CaseNum);
            List<Charge> charges = McHenryLib.ICISAdapters.ChargeAdapter.GetByCaseNumber(Globals.CaseNum);

            rptChg.DataSource = charges;
            rptChg.DataBind();

        }

       protected void rptChg_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
        {
            CaseEnt MyCase = McHenryLib.ICISAdapters.CaseAdapter.GetCaseRecordForCaseNumber(Globals.CaseNum);
            List<Charge> charges = McHenryLib.ICISAdapters.ChargeAdapter.GetByCaseNumber(Globals.CaseNum);

            if (charges != null && charges.Count > 0)
            {
                List<Sentence> sentences = new List<Sentence>();

                foreach (Charge chg in charges)
                {
                    Repeater rptSen = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("rptSen"));

                    sentences.AddRange(McHenryLib.ICISAdapters.SentenceAdapter.GetByChargeObjectID(chg.ChargeObjectID));

                    if (sentences != null && sentences.Count > 0)
                    {
                        List<SentenceDisposition> disps = new List<SentenceDisposition>();

                        foreach (Sentence sen in sentences)
                        {

                            Repeater rptDisp = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("rptDisp"));
                            disps.AddRange(McHenryLib.ICISAdapters.SentenceDispositionAdapter.GetDispositionsBySentenceOID(sen.SentenceID));

                            rptDisp.DataSource = disps;
                            rptDisp.DataBind();
                        }
                    }

                    rptSen.DataSource = sentences;
                    rptSen.DataBind();
                }
            }
         }
```

This is my ASP.NET frontend:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChg" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptChg_ItemDataBound">
<ItemTemplate>
<br />

<table class="chg">
    <tr>
        <th>Count <%#Eval("Counts") %></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<!--Builds the Charges Table-->
<table class="chg">
    <tr>
        <th>Charge Date</th>
        <th>Statute</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Disposition/Manner</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><%#Eval("ChargeDate")%></td>
        <td><%#Eval("Statute")%></td>
        <td><%#Eval("StatuteDesc")%></td>
        <td><%#ChgCode(Eval("Disposition"))%></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!--Builds the Sentences Table-->
<table class="sen">
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptSen" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <th colspan="3">Sentences</th>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <tr>
                <td><%#Eval("SentenceDate")%></td>
                <td><%#Eval("TypeDesc")%></td>
                <td><%#ZeroToNull(Eval("UnitTerm"))%> <%#ZeroToNullMoney(Eval("Amount"))%> <%#Eval("UnitTypeDesc")%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

I'm trying to get the Sentences table to repopulate for every new instance of the Charge table, with nested repeaters. However, I've tried a couple different solutions but every time the Sentences table just spits out the same data from the first charge onto all of them.

I've stepped through the code a few times, and I noticed that when it goes to DataBind the second Sentences table, the repeater's ClientID doesn't change, which makes me think that it's not rolling over a new instance of the repeater every time, and is instead just repeating the *same* data every time.

My question is: is there a way to have it manually roll a new sequential ClientID, so that it binds to the correct repeater each time? Or am I going about this completely the wrong way entirely?

Comment: This is killing the database server. MyCase and charges could be retrieved once if you make them members of the page class. Populate them in the page load event and then *use* them in the databound events. MyCase doesn't seem to be used by the databound mehtod though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove the unnecessary calls fro MyCase and charges in the `rptChg_ItemDataBound` method. You don't need to load the same over and over again for every bound `Charge` item.

You can access the **Charge** item via the **RepeaterItemEventArgs** object passed to you in the handler method.

```
protected void rptChg_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
       //check if it is a ItemTemplate. Sometimes could be a header template?
       if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
       {
         var charge = (Charge)e.Item.DataItem;
         Repeater rptSen = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("rptSen"));

        var sentences = SentenceAdapter.GetByChargeObjectID(chg.ChargeObjectID); // notice I removed the namespace for clarity, use the using statements instead

        rptSen.DataSource = sentences;
        rptSen.DataBind();
      }
    }
```

What is missing from you front, but you want to achieve from the code behind is the second repeater of the **SentenceDispositions**. This would probably go in the **ItemTemplate** of the **Sentences** repeater. Following the same pattern you can handle the **ItemDataBound** event of the *rptSen* repeater.

```
protected void rptSen_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var sentence = (SentenceDisposition)e.Item.DataItem;
        Repeater rptDisp = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("rptDisp"));

        var dispositions = SentenceDispositionAdapter.GetDispositionsBySentenceOID(sentence.SentenceID));

        rptDisp.DataSource = dispositions ;
        rptDisp.DataBind();
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Alright, thank you for the answer. I do have a lingering question though, where do I get chg from? In the old code it was in the Foreach block, where do I assign it here? As is, it says chg does not exist in this context.

Comment: Welcome. rptChg remains as it is. It is populated with data in the Page_Load.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear enough. 

I meant in 

    SentenceAdapter.GetByChargeObjectID(chg.ChargeObjectID);

It is telling me chg does not exist in this context.

Comment: I see what you mean. I renamed chg to charge. See how charge looks now. You don't need a foreach. That's the whole point.

Comment: You used the foreach to obtain a chg, but is not ok. chg was alread there, hidden in the e.Item.DataItem